# Marginal Likelihood Prior.

Tags: probability-theory

I have a model with probability matrix for a distribution of $x,y={0,1}, p(x,y\mid w)$ where $w=[w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4]$

$$p(x=0,y=0)=w_1, p(x=0,y=1)=w_2$$

$$p(x=1,y=0)=w_3, p(x=1,y=1)=(1−w_1−w_2−w_3)$$

I want to use Bayes Factors to compare it with another model, so I want to find the marginal likelihood of my model. Hence, I need a prior.

> What would you use for $p(w)$ in this case and what would be its form?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you read/check/follow the hint in my comment to your previous question? 'Cause, you see, it answers precisely this...

Comment: Your suggestion was a dirichlet but I didn't understand why and if it was chose how would the prior p(w) be written. Thanks for your effort.